# g++ vs Visual Studio

Tags: c++, g++

Can you please tell why visual studio compiles this piece of code (at the end of the message) just fine but g++ gives me an error:

```
chapter8_1.cpp:97:50: error: macro "minor" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1
chapter8_1.cpp:136:36: error: macro "minor" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1
chapter8_1.cpp:97:11: error: function definition does not declare parameters
chapter8_1.cpp: In member function ‘double Matrices::determinant(double**, int)’:
chapter8_1.cpp:136:17: error: ‘minor’ was not declared in this scope
```

Now these two functions are in a `struct`, though if I compile them in no `struct` ( simply independent functions ) then g++ gives me no error and the program works okay. The program intended to calculate the determinant of any square matrix.

Code:

```
struct Matrices
{  
.......

    double **minor(double **matrix, int dim, int row)  // row stands for the number of column that we are expanding by
    {
        int dim2 =--dim;
        double **minor2;
        minor2=new double*[dim2];                            // creates minor matrix 
        for(int i=0; i<dim2; ++i)
            minor2[i]=new double[dim2];

        for(int hhh=0; hhh<dim2; ++hhh)
            {   
                int bbb=0;
                for(int aaa=0; aaa<dim2+1; ++aaa)                  // initializing the minor matrix
                    {

                    if (aaa==row)
                        continue;
                    else
                        {
                            minor2[hhh][bbb]=matrix[hhh+1][aaa];
                            ++bbb;
                        }
                    }
                }
        return minor2;
    }

    double determinant(double **mat, int dim)
    { 
    double det=0;
    if(dim==1)
    det=mat[0][0];
    if(dim==2)
    det=mat[0][0]*mat[1][1]-mat[0][1]*mat[1][0];
    else
    {
    double ***setOFmat;                                      // pointer that points to minors
    setOFmat=new double**[dim];
    for (int ddd=0; ddd<dim; ++ddd)                         // ddd represents here the number of column we are expanding by
        setOFmat[ddd]=minor(mat, dim, ddd);
    for (int ddd=0; ddd<dim; ++ddd)                         // ddd srepresents the same here
    {

        det= det + pow(-1.0,ddd)*mat[0][ddd]*determinant(setOFmat[ddd], dim-1);    // actual formula that calculates the determinant

    }
    }
    return det;
    }
```

Comment: In a struct? You mean in a class?

Comment: Since the error messages mentions a **macro** named `minor`, it seems like there is a preprocessor macro with that name. Try renaming your function and see if it works better.

Comment: Or least define your macros in full upper case.

Comment: You have a macro `minor` defined somewhere in the include path of g++. See more here: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/132586-macro-passed-wrong-number-arguments

Comment: Yes, of course in a class. I tried that, worked just fine, thanks a lot, you are awesome.

Comment: One candidate for the macro would be some of the system headers.  There's a macro `minor` in `sysmacros.h` on my Linux box, for example (which doesn't say much for Linux).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the error messages a little more carefully :-)

> chapter8_1.cpp:97:50: error: ***macro*** "minor" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1

That means that `gcc` thinks that `minor` is a macro of some description so the preprocessing of the line:

```
double **minor(double **matrix, int dim, int row)
```

is likely to be troublesome.

I would compile it with `gcc -E` so as to get the preprocessor output, that way you'll be able to tell:

- how it's mangling your line; and
- hopefully where the `minor` macro is being defined.